# any ideas of how can I add two numbers that are saved in two structs and save them in a third struct

Tags: c, struct

I got two numbers from user and save them in two struct ,for example :

`number1 :23456`  and `number2: 244`

Now, I have to add them and save them in a third struct
(pay attention that when I get number 1 and number 2 ,I get one char at a time -which creates my number1.)
Any ideas of how can I add them using structs ?? and **not** just saving the two numbers in `int` type, adding them and them saving them in a third struct.

```
typedef struct node {
 char num;
 struct node* next;
}Node;
```

Comment: `when I get number 1 and number 2 ,I get one char at a time` why?

Comment: Its kind of a homework and they asked to get the numbers this way

Comment: I thik the addition is aritmetic addition, is that correct? I mean you add them as integer values?

Comment: yes as integer values

Comment: How do we know in which node is stored each char of number? For example all the numbers (number1, number2, etc.) are stored as an individual char of numbers in the same linked list, or each number is saved in different linked list and each linked list is consist of chars of number? Sum of my question is, Is there only one linked list which holds the all numbers or are there multiple linked lists that each holds its own particular number?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? This seems like the classic linked list addition task. In which case, you need to show us what you have tried.

Comment: Also please make it clear in your question that each node in each linked list stores one digit of the given number. So, for your example `23456` will be stored as `2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> NULL`, and 244 will be stored as `2 -> 4 -> 4 -> NULL`. The result should be the addition of these 2 lists, accounting for carry. This is just a guess as to what your actual assignment is though. But I'm pretty certain this is what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

here's the brief algorithm

- reverse number1,  number2 and alias them to tempn1, tempn2. You may use any of the methods in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/)
- create a new list (in-case if you are using some kind of initialize function) - let it be number3 and a zero initialized `carry`
- loop until none of the number1 or number2 are NULL i.e., `!tempn1 && !tempn2`

  - store result of addition in number3 - `addList(number3, (tempn1->num + tempn2->num + carry) % 10)`
  - get new carry - `carry = (tempn1->num + tempn2->num + carry) / 10`
  - increment tempn1, tempn2
- while tempn1 is not NULL

  - store result of addition in number3 - `addList(number3, (tempn1->num +  carry) % 10)`
  - get new carry - `carry = (tempn1->num + carry) / 10`
  - increment tempn1
- while tempn2 is not NULL

  - store result of addition in number3 - `addList(number3, (tempn2->num +  carry) % 10)`
  - get new carry - `carry = (tempn2->num + carry) / 10`
  - increment tempn2
- `if carry`

  - `addList(number3, carry)`
- reverse number1, number2, number3